# Printing a Python pandas data frame with padding

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a short script to validate data in a CSV and I'm formatting the results to dump to stdout and for readability, I'm adding 5 space padding on the left. Note: I'm NOT using `format` because I don't want to justify output.

Code:

```
def duplicate_data():
    dup_df = inventory_df[inventory_df.duplicated(['STORE_NO','SKU'],keep=False)]
    if dup_df.empty:
        print(five, 'INFO: No Duplicate Entries Found')
    else:
        #print('\n')
        print(five, 'WARN: Duplicate STORE_ID and SKU Data Found!')
        print(five, dup_df.to_string(index=False))
```

Results:

It all works great until it prints the data frame:

```
      WARN: Duplicate STORE_ID and SKU Data Found!
      Please Copy/Paste the following and send to the customer:
      STORE_NO            SKU  ON_HAND_QTY
10000001  1000000000007            2
10000002  1000000000007            8
```

I could iterate over the rows but the formatting is worse than the example above.

```
for rows in dup_df.iterrows():
            print(five,rows)
```

Any thoughts as to how I can format the data frame output?

Answer (score 0):

Not super nice but you could to do something like this:

```
def padlines(text, padding):
    return "\n".join(padding + l for l in text.splitlines())
```

And then `padlines(df.to_string(), five)`